# How to change default folder

Tags: php, git, github

So I'm developing with my team and we are using Github for that. Now, default folder is usually in

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\.ssh\somefolder

now when I want to commit&push changes I MUST commit from this folder, but its annoying because I'm editing and testing files on my wamp which is located on D:\wamp\www

now my question is, how to change default folder so I can pull repo and commit/push directly from my wamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move your local repository (the folder containing the `.git` subfolder and everything it contains) into the location you'd like to use.

Comment: can I move only .git folder to the www ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You do want your files over there, don't you?